# Is it possible to test radio buttons in postman with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a piece of code for an api which allows users to enter text inputs for various things but i also want to include a radio button which will let the user make a choice between 3 types of something. how can i include this in my api and how can i test it via postman?

```
  <?php
    
    
    $DBhost = "localhost";
    $DBuser = "root";
    $DBpassword = "";
    $DBname = "mytest";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($DBhost, $DBuser, $DBpassword, $DBname);
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    $n1 = $data["num1"];
    $n2 = $data["num2"];
    $n3 = $data["num3"];
   num_input(num_1,num_2,num_3)VALUES ('".$n1."','".$n2."','".$n3."')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Insert Query Failed"))
    {
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Product Inserted Successfully", "status" => true));
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(array("message" => "Failed Product Not Inserted ", "status" => false));
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: if(mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Insert Query Failed"))


this code construction will not allow reaching the else condition

Comment: what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not clear who and how is sending the request in your case, and what your form looks like.
I will proceed from your example.
Judging by this code line:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

You are using ajax request, that send json.

---

> i also want to include a radio button which will let the user make a
> choice between 3 types of something

Add to your form radio button something like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="some1" name="something" value="var1">
<label for="some1">Some 1</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="some2" name="something" value="var2">
<label for="some2">Some 2</label><br>
<input type="radio" id="some3" name="something" value="var3">
<label for="some3">Some 3</label>
```

---

> how can i include this in my api

you will get the same variable as text

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$n1 = $data["num1"];
$n2 = $data["num2"];
$n3 = $data["num3"];
$something = $data["something"];
```

By the way, you can check what you get, like this:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
var_dump($data);
die();
```

---

> how can i test it via postman

i'm not sure, but you can use something like this:

to send json in postman use request with

method = POST

add header: Content-Type = application/json

add body in json format = {"num1"="1","num2"="2","num3"="3","something"="var1"}

---

Warnings:

When you work with user data you should not trust his enter data. You need to chesk them.
You can use php pdo and bind params to prevent SQL injection.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

---

```
if(mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Insert Query Failed"))
{
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Product Inserted Successfully", "status" => true));
}
else
{
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Failed Product Not Inserted ", "status" => false));
}
```

Else code here will never reached, because if mysqli_query false die happens.
Just delete "or die(...)" fragment

---

```
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

try to use identical response

```
if (!$conn) {
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error(), "status" => false));
}
```

---

start to use psr:

- https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/
- https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/
- https://www.php-fig.org/psr/